# Issue with Laravel Guard compiling sass folders

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-4, guard, compass-sass

Lets say I have this basic folder setup...

```
// Location: app/assets/sass

folder/partial.scss
_partial.scss // in this file @import 'folder/partial.scss'
app.scss // in this file @import '_partial.scss'
```

For me, this will compile to

```
//Location: public/css

folder/partial.css
app.css
```

Is there anyway to stop Guard from compiling assets in folders in the sass directory? Do I need to have some sort of config.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I may have found a solution. Reading through the Guard Docs, I found that there is an option to set 'smart partials'

```
'smart_partials' => true,
```

So if you are using Laravel 4, and have downloaded Jeffrey Way's Laravel-Guard composer package, you would add that option like so..

```
// Location: config/packages/way/guard-laravel/guard.php

'guard_options' => array(

  'sass' => array(
    'compass'        => true,
    'smart_partials' => true,
    'style'   => ':expanded',
  )

)
```